# How to access Language Files in PHP Microframework Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am trying out the microframework Lumen by Laravel, but I can't access the language files like in laravel ... So I tryed a bit around, but I didn't figure it out. So I'm asking you.

What I did so far was to try out the `Illuminate\Translation\Translator` namespace but I get the error `BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 744:
Target [Illuminate\Translation\LoaderInterface] is not instantiable.`. I did the same thing with `Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator` but same result :(

So, does someone know how to use the language files under `resources/lang/xx/`?

Answer (score 0):

ok, already found it :)
You can still use the `trans()` helper like in laravel.

Here the link, where I found a list of helpers of Lumen: http://lumentutorial.com/2015/05/lumen-helpers/

hf! :)